# How to scale Java app in the cloud automagically?, or, is there a Heroku for Java?

Tags: java, scalability, heroku, virtualization

I recently came across Heroku, which looks extremely cool. You just upload your app and you're done; it scales without further intervention. Unfortunately, Heroku is for Ruby and our app is in Java.

It's a webapp, implemented as a .war file. We want it to scale automatically across clusters of servers maintained entirely by other people.

We've spoke to Rackspace. They have "Rackspace Cloudsites" which does this for Wordpress. They have no intention of supporting Java app servers in this way.

What else is out there?

Comment: Scaling an app is far more complicated than simply flipping a few switches.  There is no such thing as scaling "automagically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/).  In your case, the [App Engine Java Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html) will be helpful.  You can also build App Engine applications using [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html).

Answer (score 4):

The key to scalability is not the infrastructure (only). You can use various cloud offers:

- Google App Engine
- Amazon EC2
- Heroku
- [CloudFoundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/)
- VMForce (upcoming)
- etc..

But if your application is not inherently scalable, the cloud won't help you.

In fact, strictly speaking, scalability is a property of the application, and it means that the application starts supporting higher load by simply adding hardware. The cloud offers you the "adding hardware" part. The rest is your responsibility.

Now, how to achieve scalability of your application is a huge topic. [High scalability](http://highscalability.com/) is a good resource for such articles.

Answer (score 2):

Now [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) supports Java. Great value for service/price :)

Answer (score 0):

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) does this. It's all Java and Javascript (converted from Java when needed) too.